# Using DFS to check if a robotic path is possible

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am practicing using DFS to solve a robotic path problem. The robot can move only in the following two ways:

1. (x, y) -> (x, x+y)
2. (x, y) -> (x+y, y)

Given a point (10, 12), can the robot arrive at certain point (32, 22)?

I have the following code written, but it does not quite work yet, and it only works for cases like (10, 22), which is the case (x, x+y). If the test case is **(x + (x + y), x+y), e.g. (32, 22)**, my code does not work. I guess I am still confused about using DFS correctly.

```
public boolean canReach(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        return dfs(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    private boolean dfs(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
            return true;
        } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
            return false;
        } else if (x1 < x2 || y1 >= y2) {
            return dfs(x1+y1, y1, x2, y2);
        } else {
            return dfs(x1, x1+y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
```

When I draw out the graph of the DFS runs, it starts to look like a tree with each node having two children nodes. For example:

```
  (10, 12)
    /   \
(10,22) (22, 12)
```

I have also thought about creating an array `visited` of boolean to indicate whether a node has been visited, but I don't know what the size should be for such an array.

Any help is much appreciated! I really want to get some hands-on using DFS to solve such path problems.

An **alternative** solution I came up with recursion (not DFS though) works as below. In each move, either `x2 = x1` or `y2 = y1`. Therefore `x1 + y1` must be greater than `x1` or `y1`, and the 
this case must always be true: `y2 > x2` or `x2 > y2`

```
public boolean canReach2(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        return findPath(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    private boolean findPath(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
            return true;
        } else if (x2 < x1 && y2 < y1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (y2 > x2) {
                return findPath(x1, y1, x2, y2-x2);
            } else {
                return findPath(x1, y1, x2-y2, y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `return true` and `return false` branches look (almost!) right, but in all other cases, you actually need to consider both alternatives; you'll have to call `dfs` *twice* in each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public boolean findPath(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2)
        return true;
    else if (x1 > x2 || y1 > y2)
        return false;
    else
        return x1 > 0 && findPath(x1, x1 + y1, x2, y2)
            || y1 > 0 && findPath(x1 + y1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```